# How to enable HSTS with node-http-proxy?

Tags: node.js, https, node-http-proxy

Under node.js 0.8, I'm using node-http-proxy in "router table" mode configured like so:

```
var httpProxy = require("http-proxy");
var config = require("./config");

proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer({
    hostnameOnly: true,
    router: {
        "one.example.com": "localhost:9000",
        "two.example.com": "localhost:9001"
    },
    https: {
        key: config.key,
        cert: config.cert,
        // mitigate BEAST: https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2011/10/17/mitigating-the-beast-attack-on-tls
        honorCipherOrder: true,
        ciphers: "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH"
    }
})
proxyServer.listen(8000)
```

I'd like to add [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (HTTP Strict Transport Security) so that compliant browsers will be told to always use SSL.  To do this, I need to get http-proxy to add the header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=60000
```

(or other max-age).  How can I ask node-http-proxy to efficiently append this header?

Answer (score 4):

For your example, I'm not sure as it seems this older question is using `http-proxy@0.8`.  However, here's what I've done with `http-proxy@1.0.0`:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

// https server to decrypt TLS traffic and direct to a normal HTTP backend
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9009 // or whatever port your local http proxy listens on
  },
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('valid-ssl-key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('valid-ssl-cert.pem', 'utf8')
  }
}).listen(443); // HTTPS listener for the real server

// http server that redirects all requests to their corresponding
// https urls, and allows standards-compliant HTTP clients to 
// prevent future insecure requests.
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.statusCode = 301;
  res.setHeader('Location', 'https://' + req.headers.host.split(':')[0] + req.url);
  res.setHeader('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains');
  return res.end();
});

server.listen(80); // HTTP listener for the old HTTP clients
```